# react-native-track-player error the player has already been initialized via setupPlayer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-track-player

I have a react-navigation modal with react-native-track-player, closing one and opening it back throws the error `The player has already been initialized via setupPlayer`. How to make sure it runs only once? I couldn't find a method to do so.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setupPlayer();
}, []);

const setupPlayer = async() => {
  try {
    await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      capabilities: [
        Capability.Play,
        Capability.Pause,
        Capability.SkipToNext,
        Capability.SkipToPrevious
      ],
    });

    await TrackPlayer.add(podcasts);
    await gettrackdata();
    await TrackPlayer.play();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a function that runs once in App.js, and set a flag that can be later saved in context, store, or AsyncStorage if needed.

```js
async function isPlayerInitialized() {
  let isPlayerInitialized = false;

  try {
    await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      capabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause, Capability.SkipToNext, Capability.SkipToPrevious]
    });

    isPlayerInitialized = true;
  } catch (e) {
    // intentionally leaved as blank
  }
}
```

Thoughts: TrackPlayer is initialized only once, however, I don't like this approach because I have a feeling that there should be a specific method for checking if the TrackPlayer instance has already been set up.

Comment: Got a better setup yet?

Comment: @StefanFalk Nope, it works just fine so far.